# Steps not consistently firing - Google Tag Manager Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have had a Dev help me implement checkout step tracking. I can see each step get pushed through the data layer. Here's an example of the code that is pushed through:

```
{
  event: 'Checkout',
  ecommerce: {checkout: {actionField: {step: 6, option: 'Option A'}}},
  gtm.uniqueEventId: 819
}
```

However, I am *not* seeing these steps come through consistently on the GA side. Even though I see everything in GTM, only one or two steps per checkout will actually make it to GA, and it seems totally random as to which steps are being sent up.

It's very confusing.

The only thing I can figure is that these events are being pushed through Javascript after a user clicks through to the rather than through pageviews.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already pushed the first `event: 'Checkout'` make sure you call the option specifically in the next dataLayer.

```
ecommerce: {
    **checkout_option:** {
      actionField: {
        step: 6,
        option: 'Option A'
      }
```